# How to call a widget in a loop at a specific iteration value?

Tags: theme-development, customization

On the index page of my website. I want to display a widget in the third position. I am calling the widget through "the_widget( 'Widget Name' );" code. Now the problem is, since it doesn't return anything.

It will display the widget in the first position in my loop. Is there any way, I can store the widget content in a variable and display on third position. Or any other work around may be.

Thanks.

Comment: Widgets are displayed in the order you store them in the admin panel. If you put the widget in the third position in *Appearance -> Widgets* in the admin panel, it shows up in the third position on the front-end.

Comment: I am not using side bar or any such thing for widget display. I am calling them directly through the_widget() function at home page's posts loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what iteration you're on inside the main loop with `$wp_query->current_post`

```
while( have_posts() ){
    the_post();

    the_title();

    // count starts at zero, so after 1 will be after 2nd post
    if( 1 == $wp_query->current_post ){
        the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts' );
    }

}
```

#### Edit

Regarding your comment about capturing widget output, you can try PHP output buffering:

```
ob_start();
the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts' );
$widget_output = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: I have tried this. Actually the loop is storing all the values in a variable and then returning it. I am hoping if I could do this $out .= the_widget( 'Name' );

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am reading more about ob_start() and clean().